# Why didn't Walter in The Big Lebowski pull his gun in the fight with the nihilists?

Tags: the-big-lebowski

We know that Walter Sobchak carries a handgun from the time he threatened Smoky with it during league play. So when the nihilists came at them with a sword, why didn't he use his weapon?

Comment: It is alot easier to point a gun at an unarmed person than against an armed person. People with guns dont necessarily have to be brave.

Comment: Are you sure he was carrying it when the nihilists attacked?  Perhaps the bowling alley or league told him he could not bowl if he was carrying a weapon.

Comment: Walter also did a lot of talking, but is never seen taking any real action except to threaten an unarmed guy with a handgun. Not sure he actually was ready for any kind of actual action.